# What are common causes of stack overflows in C and C++ programs?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to understand more about stack overflow, I keep getting descriptions about what it is but I want to understand the causes of it, hope you can help

Comment: @Navnath it was an actual programming question about stack overflows, not about the website :)

Comment: `void foo() { foo(); }`

Comment: We are happy to help you with specific problems! Why don't you read about it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) and come back and ask when you have a specific, narrow problem? As it stands, this question is a bit wide to be constructively answered here :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158/how-does-a-stack-overflow-occur-and-how-do-you-prevent-it & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106298/what-is-causing-a-stack-overflow

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858053/when-does-the-stack-really-overflow

Comment: Deep recursion is one popular cause of stack overflows, as pointed out by @AlexFarber.

Comment: recursive, n. See `recursive`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16690326/78845#comment24019998_16690326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring an array on the stack with too many elements can do it, too:

```
int tmp[999999999];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One example is a recursion. C++ doesn't have tail call optimization, so sometimes algorithms working well in functional languages, such as Erlang or Haskell, might lead to stack overflow in C++.

UPD. Though it's not guaranteed by the standart, seems like most of modern compiler implementations do support TCO. Well, you can still reach stack overflow with deep enough recursive function by just declaring any local variables in it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure gcc can optimize tail recursion, where are you basing this on?

Comment: Hm. Indeed. I guess, my compiler is outdated.