# Insertion Sort causes Segmentation fault: 11 after scaling

Tags: c++, syntax

I wrote a simple insertion sort implementation to try to knock the rust of, and begin what I hope is a better understading of algortihms in general. The file holds 20 million random numbers. The code is below:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void insertionSort(double numbers[], int array_size);

int main() {
    int count;
    double twentyMMNumbers[20000000];
    ifstream inputFile;
    time_t now;
    time(&now);

    inputFile.open("20KRandomsNumbers.data");       //Opens input file
    if(inputFile.fail())
    {
        printf("Cannot open inputFile");
        exit(1);
    }

    count = 0;
    printf("%d\n",count);
    inputFile >> twentyMMNumbers[count];
    printf("%f\n",twentyMMNumbers[count]);
    while(inputFile)
    {   //While loop
        count++;
        if(count < 20000000)
            inputFile >> twentyMMNumbers[count];
    }
    inputFile.close();  

    printf("%s\n", ctime(&now));    //BEFORE
    insertionSort(twentyMMNumbers, 20000000); //Insertion Sort 20KRandomNumbers
    printf("%s\n", ctime(&now)); //AFTER
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%f\n",twentyMMNumbers[i]);  
}

void insertionSort(double numbers[], int array_size)
{
  int i, j, index;
  for (i=1; i < array_size; i++)
  {
    index = numbers[i];
    j = i;
    while ((j > 0) && (numbers[j-1] > index))
    {
      numbers[j] = numbers[j-1];
      j = j - 1;
    }
    numbers[j] = index;
  }
}
```

The code worked fine when it only had 20,000 entries, but now gives me:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Was this caused by my increase in the size of the array?
PS if you have any tips on optimizing this,  feels free to point it out.

Comment: This site is for reviewing working code. Better opportunities for fixing code will be found on stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't think I've ever seen a migration _to_ Stack Overflow before. Warranted, though.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, more common then you'd think. Code review gets a lot of code help questions like this.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: For what it's worth, they're not really what SO is for either. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ironically enough (given this site name), you have a stack overflow. You'll need to dynamically allocate that much memory on the heap.

For more clarity, this line:

```
double twentyMMNumbers[20000000];
```

needs to be

```
double* twentyMMNumbers = (double*)malloc(20000000*sizeof(double));
```

And of course, you'll need to free that memory before you exit your program (as a best practice):

```
free(twentyMMNumbers);
```

Comment: As another answer stated, you can also use `new`. I missed that this is C++, not C, so I used `malloc`. Either will work in C++ though.

Answer (score 2):

It works with smaller array size so here are some comments (since it was on CodeReview) and some fixes for bigger array sizes.

1, If you want to use fixed size arrays use a constant instead of the `200000` (or `20000000`) literals.

2, Using dynamic arrays is more better. Allocate the memory after you have read the first line and use the readed size as the size of the new array. Furthermore I would store the size of the data file (the first line of the file) in a separate variable, not in the array.

```
int dataSize;
inputFile >> dataSize;
double *twentyMMNumbers = new double[dataSize];
```

It allocates the exact amount of memory. No more, no less.

It also fixes the *Segmentation fault* error. For more infomartion check this question: [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1847789/843804)

(Don't forget to unallocate the array with `delete[]`.)

3, It's unnecessary to read the whole file if you have more records than the size of the array. I'd modify the while loop:

```
while (inputFile) {   
    if (count >= dataSize) {

        break;
    }
    inputFile >> twentyMMNumbers[count];
    count++;
}
inputFile.close();
```

Maybe an `exit(-1)` and an error message would be better instead of the `break`.

4, The following comment is unneccesary:

```
//While loop
```

5, You should pass the real size of the array to the `insertionSort` function, so write this:

```
insertionSort(twentyMMNumbers, dataSize);
```

The comment here is also unnecessary.

6, Improve error handling: what happens when the value of `dataSize` is bigger than the number of the numbers in the file?

7, I would extract a `printArray` function with the last `for` loop as well as a `readInput` function.

8, Consider using C++ style printing instead of `printf`s:

```
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
```

(`#include <iostream>` is required.)

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your while loop:

```
while(inputFile)
{   //While loop
    count++;
    if(count < 20000000)
        inputFile >> twentyMMNumbers[count];
}
```

This loop will only terminate if the file contains <=20000000 numbers. If count becomes 20000000, it will not try to read anymore from `inputFile`, but still use `inputFile` as the condition to continue the loop. And then when count reaches the maximum `int` value, it will wrap around and you will index `twentyMMNumbers` with a negative number. This could very well be the reason you get a segmentation fault.

20000000 is a "magic number" in your code. Instead of writing it every where make a `const int NumElements = 20000000` at the beginning of your file.