# Segmentation Fault - Large Array

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am having an odd error when I try to compile my code, which is written in C. The error says

```
 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In my code, I have a lot of really large double arrays (like of sizes close to 100,000 in length). I initialize one array of doubles and when I try to initialize an array immediately afterwards of the same size (roughly a 100,000 length) it gives me the segmentation fault error. Oddly, it depends on the size of the array. For example if I do

```
 double arr[70000];
```

It gives me the segmentation error but

```
 double arr[60000];
```

does not gives me the error. I am running my code on a linux machine if that helps. I really need many different very large double arrays. What is going on?

Comment: have you tried using gdb?

Comment: Are these array locals?  If so, you're getting a stack overflow...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes?rq=1

Comment: 60,000 doubles fit into a half-megabyte of stack; 70,000 doubles don't.  I guess your stack size is half a megabyte.  Or, more likely, your stack size is larger, but you've enough of these largish arrays that you have blown the limits.  Use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al) to allocate the arrays on the heap.  Make sure you free every allocation; you will run out of heap if you don't.  (And check that every allocation is successful before using the pointer returned!)

Comment: The proposed duplicate question is nominally for C++, and is dealing with larger array sizes (4 MiB instead of 0.5 MiB), but is otherwise very likely to be the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've encountered a "Stack Overflow"; basically, you've exhausted the stack space available to your program.

If you allocate the arrays on the heap (in heap storage), you probably will be okay.

With C, you'd likely use the **`malloc`** instruction to allocate the memory.

And of course, you'll remember to use the **`free`** instruction to return the memory when you're done with it.