# Selection of maximum sub-array from the array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, recursion, runtime-error

Given an array of length `n`, it is required to find the maximum sum of elements one can choose if it is not allowed to choose more than two consecutive elements of the array. For example;

```
n=5;
arr[5] = {10,3,5,7,3};
Output : 23
10+3+7+3=23
```

So I have written this code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int max=0;
void solve(int arr[],int ind,int sum,int n,int count)
{
    if(ind==n){
          if(sum>max)
              max=sum;
      }
      else{
          sum+=arr[ind];
          if(ind==n-1)
            solve(arr,ind+1,sum,n,1);
          if(ind==n-2 && count>1)
            solve(arr,ind+2,sum,n,1);
          if(ind<n-1 && count<2){
              count++;
              solve(arr,ind+1,sum,n,count);
          }
          if(ind<n-2)
              solve(arr,ind+2,sum,n,1);
          if(ind<n-3)
              solve(arr,ind+3,sum,n,1);
      }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i=0,arr[n];
    while(i<n){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    int count=1;
    //going into all three possibilities
    solve(arr,0,0,n,count);
    solve(arr,1,0,n,count);
    solve(arr,2,0,n,count);
    printf("%d\n",max);
    return 0;
}
```

This program produces the expected outputs for `n<1000` but shows runtime error (SIGSEGV) for larger inputs. What may be the reason?
More effective solutions are also welcome.....

Comment: Maybe stack overflow caused by too-deep recursion? But the number may be too small to cause it?

Comment: Please try using debugger first to determine where the SIGSEGV is caused.

Comment: It is given that `n<200000` and `arr[i]<10000`....will it cause overflow..

Comment: You've got about 30 bytes of information on the stack for each level of recursion. So `n=33000` will put about 1 megabyte on the stack. That could be enough to overflow the stack.

Comment: @user3386109 can you suggest another approach to this problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segmentation Fault - Large Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375801/segmentation-fault-large-array)

Comment: @yobro97 Yup, I've posted an answer that shows an alternate approach to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use dynamic programming

DP[i]: maximum from "i" index

there are 7 cases:

1- use the first and second elements

2- use the second and third elements

3- use the first and third elements

4- use only the first element

5- use only the second element

6- use only the third element

7- use none of the elements

```
int F(int[] a)
    {
        if (a.Length == 1)
        {
            return Max(a[0], 0);
        }
        int n = a.Length;
        int[] DP = new int[n];
        DP[n - 1] = Max(a[n - 1], 0);
        DP[n - 2] = DP[n - 1] + Max(a[n - 2], 0);
        for (int i = n - 3; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            DP[i] = Max(a[i], 0) + Max(a[i + 1], 0) + (i + 3 < n ? DP[i + 3] : 0);// first and second
            DP[i] = Max(DP[i], Max(a[i + 1], 0) + Max(a[i + 2], 0) + (i + 4 < n ? DP[i + 4] : 0));// second and third
            DP[i] = Max(DP[i], Max(a[i + 0], 0) + Max(a[i + 2], 0) + (i + 4 < n ? DP[i + 4] : 0));// first and third
            DP[i] = Max(DP[i], Max(a[i + 0], 0) + (i + 2 < n ? DP[i + 2] : 0));// first
            DP[i] = Max(DP[i], Max(a[i + 1], 0) + (i + 3 < n ? DP[i + 3] : 0));// second
            DP[i] = Max(DP[i], Max(a[i + 2], 0) + (i + 4 < n ? DP[i + 4] : 0));// third
            DP[i] = Max(DP[i], DP[i + 1]);// none
        }
        return DP[0];
    }
```

example1:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 10, 3, 5, 7, 3 };
writer.WriteLine(F(a));
```

output:

> 23

example2:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 5, 2, 6, 9, 8, 20, 12, 41, 3, 0, 9, 95, 6, 74, 85, 20, 14, 26, 35, 14, 72, 15 };
writer.WriteLine(F(a));
```

output:

> 496

[Implementation in C](http://scod.ir/YjW)

Comment: The OP uses **C** and not **C++**

Comment: @mojtaba357 could you please convert the above code to c as  Michi mentioned......I could understand the basic idea though....it would be more helpful to me if in c....Thanks..

Comment: @yobro97 added to end. check it.

Comment: the OP is looking for solution that scale to an array of length n, and your code is just for the example he provided n=5. how would you change your code to scale to an array of any size?

Comment: @AbdulelahAlJeffery you can send array(any size) to function and get answer :|

Comment: @AbdulelahAlJeffery 'your code is just for the example he provided n=5' why you say that?! I updated second example

Comment: +1 for the DP solution, it was an oversight from my part .. now I'm looking carefully to the code, definitely thumps up.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has a fairly simple dynamic programming solution.

Each item in the array represents a binary choice: it can either be selected or not. But if two consecutive items are selected, then the next item cannot be selected. So for each item in the array we need to keep track of three sums

- the best sum if the current item *is not* selected
- the best sum if the current item *is* selected, and the previous item was *not* selected
- the best sum if the current item *is* selected, and the previous item was selected

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define max3(a) (a[0]>a[1] ? a[0]>a[2]?a[0]:a[2] : a[1]>a[2]?a[1]:a[2])

int main( void )
{
    int array[] = { 10,3,7,55,60,62,4,2,5,42,8,9,12,5,1 };
    int N = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    int dp[N][3];

    dp[0][0] = 0;
    dp[0][1] = array[0];
    dp[0][2] = 0;
    for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ )
    {
        dp[i][0] = max3(dp[i-1]);
        dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][0] + array[i];
        dp[i][2] = dp[i-1][1] + array[i];
    }
    printf( "%d\n", max3(dp[N-1]) );
}
```

The output of this program is `208`. To understand how that was computed, take a look at the contents of the `dp` array:

[image]

Note that the correct path through the `dp` array is not known until the end. In this example, two endpoints have the same sum, so there are two paths through the array that give the same answer. The two paths represent these choices:

```
array:  10  3  7 55 60 62  4  2  5 42 8  9 12 5  1 
red:    10    +7   +60+62    +2   +42+8   +12+5     = 208  
blue:   10    +7   +60+62       +5+42   +9+12   +1  = 208
```