# Segmentation fault during the initialization of array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have seen segmentation fault sometimes during the initialization of  an array with huge size.

For ex:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string h;
    cin >> h;
    int size=h.size();
    cout << size << endl;
    int arr[size][size];
    cout << arr[0][0]<<endl;
    arr[0][0]=1;
    cout << arr[0][0]<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

When the user input is a small string lets say `"sample"` the program is working fine.

When the user input is a big string where the size is for ex. `>1500`.Segmentation is seen during the initialization of the array  `int arr[size][size];`

What can be the issue?Is there any problem in initializating the array like the one above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are out of memory with those initializations, causing a stack overflow. I recommend to allocate it on the heap or by using a std:vector. See here: [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

I think an array's size must always be a compile-time constant in C++ i.e. the value of your 'size' variable must be known at compile time.

If you want dynamic storage, use std::vector

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6.aspx) states that the default stack size on Windows is 1 MB - in case of 1500 elements in each dimension your array would take up `1500 * 1500 * 4 bytes = 9000000 bytes = 8.58 megabytes`, not sure about Linux ([this](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt) states it to be 8 MB) - I guess it depends on the compiler and distributive. So either:

1) If you know that there is a limit for the string length increase the stack size accordingly with the `/STACK` linker flag on Windows or like posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com) answer on Linux

2) Allocate the array on heap - if you don't want to mess around with memory allocations std::vector or [std::unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) can be used as a container