# Segmentation fault on large array declaration

Tags: c, arrays

I want to declare an unsigned long long array with 2mil. elements. When I first define the length of the array **const** and then define the array I get a segmentation fault error. However when I define the length just as unsigned long long the declaration works.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const unsigned long long lim = 2000000; //If I omit const, it works.
    unsigned long long nums2lim[lim];

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Does anybody know why the segmentation fault is thrown?

Comment: This does not look like C++

Comment: Your stack is most likely not big enough for 2 million unsigned long longs.

Comment: Local variables, including arrays, are stored at the stack, and the stack is limited. On Windows the default stack is just a single megabyte, on Linux it's 8 MB. Your array is almost *sixteen* MB.

Comment: _"Does anybody know why the segmentation fault is thrown?"_ Most probably because 8*2000000 exceeds your available stack size.

Comment: Also, `exit` should probably be `return` instead.

Comment: If a long-long is 64-bits (8byte), then 2,000,000 of them is 16mega-bytes... on the stack.  Hint: How big is your normal stack size?  (on most machines, its about 1 or 2 megs)

Comment: None of this explains why the declaration "works" (doesn't segfault) if the `const` qualifier is removed.  That's interesting.  What compiler are you using (gcc, Visual Studio, ...)?

Comment: The compiler is gcc and it is running on OS X.

Comment: It *might* be because gcc treats the array as a constant length array if you declare `lim` as `const`, and variable length array if you don't. But I have no further evidence to back up this theory and this is only a wild guess.

Comment: Related: C++ canonical Q&A answer that suggests new/delete or std::vector for the same problem: [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1847789)

Answer (score 3):

The auto memory (used in local arrays) has a limit well below the allocatable memory.

You can do practically the same with this (it uses pointers)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long long lim = 2000000;
    unsigned long long *nums2lim=malloc(lim*sizeof(unsigned long long));

    free(nums2lim); // don't forget this!

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: And using `free` when the array is not necessary any longer.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger, yes, I'm always forgetting about this when posting answers... Thank you for noticing this, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Indeed it is a nice approach, but this doesn't explain why it crashes when I declare  lim as cont unsigned long long.

Answer (score 1):

I have not been able to reproduce this behavior on my SLES 10 box (gcc 4.1.2, yes it's old).  I get a segfault regardless of how `lim` is declared.

I'm going to go way, way, way, *way* out on a very skinny limb and point out that your definition of `main` is incorrect; `argv` should not be declared `const` (the standard mandates that the strings pointed to by the `argv` array should be modifiable).  That bit of undefined behavior *might* be enough to cause the difference, but I seriously doubt it.

Either way, attempting to allocate 2 million *anything* in an `auto` array (VLA or not) is almost always bad juju.  Maybe when computer memory is regularly measured in terabytes it won't be a problem anymore, but for now it's going to be bigger than the runtime stack is usually prepared to handle.

You have a few options available.  One, you can declare the array with `static` storage duration, either by declaring it at file scope (outside of any function) or with the `static` keyword.  Note this means you will *not* be able to use the `lim` variable to specify the size (even though you declare it `const`, `lim` is not a *constant expression*; its value is not known at compile time):

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  static unsigned long long nums2lim[2000000];
  ...
}
```

Alternately, you can allocate it from the heap at runtime:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  const unsigned long long lim=2000000;
  int *nums2lim = malloc( sizeof *nums2lim * lim );
  if ( nums2lim )
  {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do this in C++ to allocate data in the heap:

```
const unsigned long long lim = 2000000;
unsigned long long *nums2lim = new unsigned long long[lim];
...
delete [] nums2lim;
```

Comment: The question is tagged C, so no `new` or `delete` expressions. And @TheParamagneticCroissant, no `std::vector` either.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry, missed the removal of the C++ tag. I *hate* it when people tag their questions with both C++ and C and then subsequently remove one of them. It's just wrong.