# matrix vector multiplication mpi

Tags: mpi

I wanna do matrix vector multiplication.  The code is compiling but not running. Can anyone please help me out in solving the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
#include "mpi.h" 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIM 500

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, n=10000; 
    int nlocal;        /* Number of locally stored rows of A */ 
    double *fb;
    double a[DIM * DIM], b[DIM], x[DIM];     /* Will point to a buffer that stores the entire vector b */ 
    int npes, myrank; 
    MPI_Status status; 

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    /* Get information about the communicator */ 
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &npes);  

    /* Allocate the memory that will store the entire vector b */ 
    fb = (double*)malloc(npes * sizeof(double)); 
    nlocal = n / npes; 

    /* Gather the entire vector b on each processor using MPI's ALLGATHER operation */ 
    MPI_Allgather(b, nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, fb, nlocal, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 

    /* Perform the matrix-vector multiplication involving the locally stored submatrix */ 
    for (i = 0; i < nlocal; i++) { 
        x[i] = 0.0; 
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            x[i] += a[i * n + j] * fb[j]; 
    } 
    free(fb);
    MPI_Finalize();   
} //end main
```

Please help me out in running the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Gilles its compiling now but not running. Please check

Comment: @Gilles its 10000..edited in the code

Answer (score 2):

The issue may come from `fb = (double*)malloc(npes * sizeof(double));` which should be `fb = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));`. Indeed, `npes` is the number of processes and `n` is the total length of the vector.

Moreover, the array `a` is of size 500x500=250000. This is enough to store 25 rows if n=10000... Are you using 400 processes ? If you are using less that 400 processes `a[i * n + j]` is an attempt to read after the end of the array. It triggers undefined behaviors, such as a segmentation fault.

Last `a` is a large array and since it is declared as `double a[500*500]`, it is allocated on the stack. Read : [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes) : the best way to go is to use `malloc()` for `a` as well, with appropiate size (here `nlocal*n`).

```
double *a=malloc(nlocal*n*sizeof(double));
if(a==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"process %d : malloc failed\n",npes);exit(1);}
...
free(a);
```

`n=10000` is rather large. Consider using computed numbers such as `nlocal*n` for the size of the array `a`, not default sizes such as `DIM`. That way, you will be able to debug your code on smaller `n` and memory will not be wasted.

The same comments apply to `b` and `x` allocated as `double b[500]` and `double x[500]` while much larger arrays are needed if `n=10000`. Once again, consider using `malloc()` with the appropriate number, not a defined value `DIM=500` !

```
double *b=malloc(n*sizeof(double));
if(b==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"process %d : malloc failed\n",npes);exit(1);}
...
free(b);

double *x=malloc(nlocal*sizeof(double));
if(x==NULL){fprintf(stderr,"process %d : malloc failed\n",npes);exit(1);}
...
free(x);
```

A debugger such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can detect such problems related to memory management. Try it on your program using a single process !