# Solving segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

void main() {
   int i,j; 
   int *u = malloc(10000 * 10000 * sizeof(int));   
 for (i=0; i<10000; i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<10000;j++)
       {
            u[i][j]=i+j;   
       }
   }
    free(u); 
}
```

I edited my program. when compiling this program, I get an error "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector".
how can i allocate memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Comment: I think the standard stack size on windows is about 8MB, assuming you're on a 32bit system, `double u[10000][10000];` attempts to allocate around 48MB.

Comment: i know how to use malloc for allocate memory for array, but i don't know how can i allocate memory for matrix?

Comment: Please don't edit the question so that it suddenly asks a new question entirely. This creates a mess out of the posted answers. After your edit, neither the question nor any answers make any sense. What you should have done here was to create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have allocated memory for a single dimensional array and you are trying to use it as a two-dimensional array. There is a slight alteration which you need to do to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main() {
   int i,j; 
   int *u = malloc(10 * 10 * sizeof(int));   
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<10;j++)
       {
            u[10*i +j]=i+j; // this is how you can use it   
       }
   }
   for (i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<10;j++)
       {
            printf("%d ",u[10 *i +j]);   
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   free(u); 
   return 0;
}
```

Note that I have used size 10*10, you can do the same for whatever size you need.

[Check-here](http://ideone.com/AdZ7Tz)

Answer (score -1):

You can't allocate large arrays on heap directly in the declaration.
You can allocate large arrays using malloc as follows

`#include <stdlib.h>
int *matrix = malloc(ROW * COLUMNs * sizeof(int));`

Always use column major order to search for elements.
Explanation for column major order can be found here [Accessing elements in a matrix](http://www.cbseguy.com/row-column-major-address-calculations-cbse/)

Here size = 10000
Always after you complete your task,free the memory

`free(matrix);`

Comment: i need a matrix not array

Comment: (#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  


void main() {
   int i,j; 
   int *u = malloc(10000 * 10000 * sizeof(int));

 for (i=0; i<10000; i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<10000;j++)
       {
            u[i][j]=i+j;   
       }
   }
    free(u); 
}     )                                                                                                                      it has an error"subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector"

Comment: @user7671105 It should be `u[10000*i + j]`

Comment: Didn't this answer,answer your question?

Comment: @bigbounty no it didn't