# vector<int> a[n] allocated in stack or heap? Difference between the declarations vector<vector<int>>a(n) and vector<int>a[n]?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

When I declare vector< vector< int>> a(n), memory is allocated in heap whereas when I declare it vector< int> a[n], it is allocated on stack. But why? Doesn't the second one mean the way- a[i] is a pointer to the i-th vector, as the vectors are dynamically allocated in heap and hence the whole allocation should be in heap. Isn't it?

Could you please explain me if I am wrong?

Comment: VLA are not part of C++, it is C that supported by some compilers in C++ mode.

Comment: This is a VLA variant of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes

Comment: Good spot jxh.  I should have gone looking for that dupe, rather than trying to answer.

Comment: Subject for this topic should be "Welcome to Stack Overflow" with double meanings...

Comment: If you know that a vector is a dynamic array, why not do the common sense thing and make a vector (dynamic array) of vector<int>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<int> adj[n];
```

This is not legal C++ code, you are not allowed to declare a dynamicaly sized array on the stack like this.

It's also probably the cause of your issue, as making such a huge allocation on the stack can cause some major issues.

You should use the following instead:

```
vector<vector<int>> adj(n);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  While the statement is true, it is obviously an extension supported by his compiler, and is not really the cause of his problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's legal for some compilers.  Although I've never run across one, myself.

Comment: @zzyz some compilers letting you do it does not make it legal C++. Otherwise the same could be said of any undefined behavior, or strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @MartinBonner Added the explanation as to why I believe it's the root of the issue OP is trying to solve. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank Fair enough, and upvoted your answer based on your edit.

Comment: Actually it should be `vector<vector<int>> adj(n, {1} );` which would even eliminate next loop

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned,

```
vector<int> adj[n];
```

is not standard C++, however some compilers (GCC) allow it as extension.

However such array is then created on the stack, and what you likely see is stack overflow (pun intended) - the stack is usually much smaller than the heap memory.