# Cuda Basic Program (Write values to matrix and std:cout does not work) ; Main function does not start

Tags: c++, cuda, std, cout

I wrote a pretty simple Cuda Program. I would like to assign values to a matrix in device memory. Then I want  to copy the values to the host and display them. The program I wrote does not work. But I don't know why. I tried to figure out what I do wrong by displaying the status with cout, but even this does not work, so I am thinking that the main function is not starting.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Here is my code:

```
    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    const int N = 1024;


    __global__ void matrix(float *d_A)
    {
        int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;


        int index = col + row * N;
        if (col < N && row < N)
        {
            d_A[index] = 255;
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "Programm begins";
        float A[N * N];
        float d_A[N * N];

        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, (N * N)*sizeof(float));
        std::cout << "Matrizes allocated";
        std::cout << A[0] << " , " << A[1] << " , " << A[2] << " , " << A[3] << " , " << A[4] << " , " << A[5] << "\n";
        std::cout << A[1024] << " , " << A[1025] << " , " << A[1026] << " , " << A[1027] << " , " << A[1028] << " , " << A[1029] << "\n";
        matrix << <1024, 1024 >> >(d_A);
        std::cout << "Wrote Matrix to local device memory";
        std::cout << d_A[0] << " , " << d_A[1] << " , " << d_A[2] << " , " << d_A[3] << " , " << d_A[4] << " , " << d_A[5] << "\n";
        std::cout << d_A[1024] << " , " << d_A[1025] << " , " << d_A[1026] << " , " << d_A[1027] << " , " << d_A[1028] << " , " << d_A[1029] << "\n";


        cudaMemcpy(A, d_A, N * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        std::cout << "Wrote Matrix to host memory";
        std::cout << A[0] << " , " << A[1] << " , " << A[2] << " , " << A[3] << " , " << A[4] << " , " << A[5] << "\n";
        std::cout << A[1024] << " , " << A[1025] << " , " << A[1026] << " , " << A[1027] << " , " << A[1028] << " , " << A[1029] << "\n";

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes . Even after you change that, I see several other problems which will prevent the code from working

Comment: As a general comment, float d_a[N * N] is allocating host memory as well as allocating device memory with cudaMalloc, you should really declare it as float *d_A (a pointer), and then free the memory at the end of the program.  Also, I'd try a device function much simpler as a starter, such as d_A[threadIdx.x] = 1;

Comment: thank you, so when I don't use cudaMalloc, d_A is also located in the device? I deleted the cuda Malloc command. But the program is still teh same. Its displaying no "cout" output. Do you know waht might cause this?

Comment: You must use cudaMalloc for d_A. And you cannot print its contents on the host

Comment: @talononmies: thank you! you are right I am getting a stackoverflow. Could I solve this problem with textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code you have provided.

1. De-referencing device memory from the host e.g. `d_A[0]` is illegal and will result in undefined behavior.
2. Treating the data as 2 dimensional inside the kernel whereas the grid and block are provide as 1 dimensional. In this case, the `row` variable will always be 0 and will essentially play no role in calculation of `index`. Define grid and block sizes as `dim3` type to create 2D grid and block.
3. It is not recommended to create large size arrays on the stack such as `float A[N*N];`. Prefer dynamic memory allocation with `new` operator.
4. Allocation of device memory to already allocated host array `d_A` is undefined behavior. If you want to allocate device memory to a variable, just declare it as a simple pointer like `float* d_A;`.

The fixed code may look like this:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
const int N = 1024;

__global__ void matrix(float *d_A)
{
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;


    int index = col + row * N;
    if (col < N && row < N)
    {
        d_A[index] = 255;
    }
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Programm begins"<<std::endl;
    float *A = new float[N*N];
    float *d_A;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, (N * N)*sizeof(float));
    std::cout << "Matrizes allocated"<<std::endl;
    std::cout << A[0] << " , " << A[1] << " , " << A[2] << " , " << A[3] << " , " << A[4] << " , " << A[5] <<std::endl;
    std::cout << A[1024] << " , " << A[1025] << " , " << A[1026] << " , " << A[1027] << " , " << A[1028] << " , " << A[1029] <<std::endl;

    dim3 block(32,32);
    dim3 grid;
    grid.x = (N + block.x - 1) / block.x;
    grid.y = (N + block.y - 1) / block.y;

    matrix << <grid, block >> >(d_A);
    std::cout << "Wrote Matrix to local device memory"<<std::endl;

    cudaMemcpy(A, d_A, N * N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << "Wrote Matrix to host memory"<<std::endl;
    std::cout << A[0] << " , " << A[1] << " , " << A[2] << " , " << A[3] << " , " << A[4] << " , " << A[5] <<std::endl;
    std::cout << A[1024] << " , " << A[1025] << " , " << A[1026] << " , " << A[1027] << " , " << A[1028] << " , " << A[1029] <<std::endl;

    cudaFree(d_A);
    delete[] A;

    return 0;
}
```

It is highly recommended to [add error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) for each CUDA API call to ease the debugging process.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. thank you also for explining me what my mistakes were. This is was very helpful as I am a beginner, and as you see, the simplest problems are a big challenge for me ;-)

Comment: @MarcelRudolf... You are welcome. Everyone is a beginner at some point. You may consider accepting an answer if your problem is solved. That will help future users if they encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few issues with your code, I'd simplify the code even further if this is your first steps into Cuda and C++.  Try this out (important changes surrounded by comment stars);

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

const int Grids = 256;
const int Threads = 256;

__global__ void matrix(float *d_A)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    d_A[idx] = 1.0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Programm begins";

    // ****
    float *A = new float[Grids * Threads];
    float *d_A;
    // ****

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, (Grids * Threads)*sizeof(float));

    matrix<<<Grids, Threads>>>(d_A);

    cudaMemcpy(A, d_A, Grids * Threads*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i < (Grids * Threads); ++i)
    {
         cout << A[i] << ",";
    }

    // ****
    cudaFree(d_A);
    delete A;
    // ****  

    return 0;
}
```

Also have a look here for basic examples, https://devblogs.nvidia.com/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c/

A couple of issues here;

1) The host memory you're allocating N * N (1024 * 1024) is a large amount and may not be available from the heap

2) When you declared the d_A variable you also declared host memory, as well as device memory for it, which is not required

3) You didn't free the device memory for d_A

4) Your device/GPU may not be capable of running 1024 threads at once; in which case it may fail silently and you will end up with your kernel not running.