# When I use fread with a 34 mb .mp4 file I get a segmentation fault, how can I solve it?

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fread

I'm trying to write code that can reverse a file to make it unreadable. I did this in Python and I'm trying to do it again in C, but when I use fread to read a large file I get a segmentation fault (with files with 1 or 2 mb this doesn't happen), is there anything I can do to solve this?

I tried with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fh=fopen("vid.mp4","rb");
    FILE *fh1=fopen("vid1.png","wb");

    int fsize=36886031;
    char data[fsize];

    fread(data,fsize,1,fh); //<-- error
    fwrite(data,fsize,1,fh1); //<-- error too
}
```

And i get:

Segmentation fault
[Progam finished]

Comment: `char data[fsize];` ==> `char *data = malloc(fsize); if (!data) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`... and remember to `free(data)` when you no longer need it.

Comment: Probably not your issue, but you forgot to verify that the files could be opened successfully before you pass the pointers to `fread` function.

Comment: In C, local variables are typically (not defined by the standard) located on the stack which is only a few MB in size. Exact size depends on OS and settings. An array of 34MB ist very likely too large for your stack causing stack overflow error. The solution is what pmg mentioned above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable inside a function like this, you're declaring it on the stack. It is big enough to hold a lot of normal variables, but it usually doesn't have enough memory to hold big arrays. If you want to store big objects, you must use `malloc`.

Here, I've modified your code to not crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fh=fopen("vid.mp4","rb");
    size_t fsize = 36886031;
    char *data = malloc(fsize);
    if (data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fread(data, fsize, 1, fh);
    free(data); // Don't forget to free this memory
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I highly recommend reading about dynamic memory allocation, because it is a very important part of C language.

Comment: No @DEV, that modification is unnecessary. Make sure your compiler is properly configured: `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error bad compiler` / `#endif`

Comment: @pmg Yes, I looked and discovered that just use a typecast

Comment: Just do: ```char *data=(char*)malloc(fsize);```

Comment: I'm new at this

Comment: @DEV Casting `malloc` is a bad practice in C. Here is a link explaining why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @Nierusek Wouldn't hurt to swap `cnt` and `size` parameters AND to verify that `fread()` was able to slurp in all that was expected, swapped or not...