# Why does my code break for huge integer values?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and was doing project Euler problem 3, my code works for reasonably sized integer values for the variable "number", I was wondering what is going wrong, I get error messages for Segmentation faults and Arithmatic exceptions, I rewrote it a couple of times and tried to clear it up, but cannot seem to find the place where it goes wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool is_coprime(int larger, int smaller)
{
    // cout << smaller << endl;
    return (larger % smaller != 0);
}

int find_next_prime(int* primme_pntr, int* cur_ind_pntr)
{
    bool found = false;
    bool quit = false;
    int k;

    if (*cur_ind_pntr == 0) {
        k = 1;
    } else {
        k = *(primme_pntr + *cur_ind_pntr -1) - 1;
    }

    while (not found) {
        k++;
        quit = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < *cur_ind_pntr; i++) {
            
            if (not is_coprime(k,*(primme_pntr + i))) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        if (not quit) {
            return k;
        }
    
    }

}

void append(int* list_pntr, int* cur_ind_pntr, int value) 
{
    *(list_pntr + *cur_ind_pntr) = value;
    *cur_ind_pntr += 1;
}

int reducer(int* p_pntr, int* cur_ind_pntr, int value)
{
    int cur_prime;

    for (int i = 0; i < *cur_ind_pntr; i++) {
        cur_prime = *(p_pntr + i);

        cout << "sent from primechecker" << endl;
        if (not is_coprime(value, cur_prime)) {
            return cur_prime;
        }
    }

    bool found = false;
    int next_prime;

    while (not found) {
        next_prime = find_next_prime(p_pntr, cur_ind_pntr);
        append(p_pntr, cur_ind_pntr, next_prime);

        if (not is_coprime(value, next_prime)) {
            found = true;
            return next_prime;
        }

    }

}




int main()
{
    int size = 10000;
    int Primes[size];
    int *p_pntr = Primes;

    int cur_ind = 0;
    int* cur_ind_pntr = &cur_ind;
    
    int number = 22143223844;
    int max_prime = 0;
    int cur_prime;

    while (number != 1) {
        cur_prime = reducer(p_pntr, cur_ind_pntr, number);
        max_prime = max(max_prime, cur_prime);
    
        number /= cur_prime;

        cout << ".. " << cur_prime << endl;
    }

}
```

I tried keeping track of where the function callings that resulted in errors came from, but cannot seem to pin down the problem.

Comment: [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Comment: @user12002570 I don’t think that’s obviously related. 10k entries for a stack-based array is a lot, but there’s only one such array created, no recursion, and the issue stems from a large value in `number`, not the stack-based array size.

Comment: You are making compilers nervous with `while (not found)` since _if_ that loop is exited because of that condition, the function will end without returning an `int` as promised. Make it `while(true)` instead - Also, you are using VLAs (variable length arrays) which are not part of standard C++. Use `std::vector`s instead.

Comment: Btw, 22143223844 is probably to big to fit in an `int`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That may be, but still I bet there are plenty of other dupes for the other problem in OP's code. The dupe list can be edited to show the same.

Comment: 22143223844 is over ten times too large for an `int`.

Comment: For competitive coding, it’s generally safer to use `long` instead of `int` as the problems are likely break 32-bits limit quickly.

Comment: @QuangHoang `long` (a.k.a `long int`) and `int` are often the same width.

Comment: There are couple serious mistakes in this code which compiler finds as warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/187nEsYj6

Comment: After silencing/patching warnings your code has buffer overflow error: https://godbolt.org/z/M4EYaq1Gd

Comment: Project Euler is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. Project Euler is not meant to be a platform for learning C++, but it is designed for someone who already has established programming and development experience and who has some free time to spare for solving random mathematical problems. The only realistic way to learn that hardest and the most difficult general purpose programming language in use to day [is with a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: If you can, use types like `uint64_t` as it makes it abundantly clear what the numerical range is. `long int` is not as obvious.