# Do you cast the result of malloc?

Tags: c++, malloc

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array), someone suggested in a comment that I should not cast the results of `malloc`, *i.e*:

```
int *sieve = malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
```

Rather than:

```
int *sieve = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
```

Why would this be the case?

**EDIT**
Marked as duplicate cause I did not research enough.

Comment: In C++, you have to cast. The point was about C.

Comment: The linked question is for C but your question is for C++. These are two very different languages and suggestions for one can not necessarily be applied to the other.

Comment: You have no choice in C++; no implicit conversion exists. Of course, the question should be "why am I using `malloc` in C++?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C, you can implicitly convert from a `void*` (the return type of `malloc`) to any other pointer type. Therefore, the cast isn't required, and it's considered good C style to leave the cast off.

In C++, you *cannot* implicitly convert from a `void*` to any other pointer type, so the cast would be required. That said, in C++, you should almost certainly be using `new` and `delete` rather than `malloc`, as they're more type-safe, play well with constructors and destructors, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: new and delete are different. They create objects as well as allocate memory. If you are writing an allocator that is going to just get memory you might implement it with malloc.

Of course you are not going to just rewrite malloc, so perhaps you are going to do something else clever with it too.

Comment: @CashCow In C++, wouldn't `operator new` and `operator delete` be more appropriate low-level allocators?