# produce max, min and meanarithmetic mean in C

Tags: c, max, min

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main( void )
{
    float values[999999];
    int number = 0;
    float max = -100000, min = 100000, total = 0, mean = 0;

    while ((scanf("%f", &values[number++])) != EOF )
    for(int a = 0; a < number; a++) {
        total = total + values[a];
        if (values[a] > max) { max = values[a]; }
        if (values[a] < min) { min = values[a]; }
    }
    mean = total / (float)(number-1);
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", min, max, mean);
    printf("%f", total);
    printf("%d", number);
}
```

and i got result like that:

```
5.6
6
7
5.60 7.00 11.93
35.800003
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I expected the mean to be `6.2`, not `11.93`.

Comment: What is your input? What is your output? What is your expected output?

Comment: `float values[999999];` that's a rather big array to place on stack. maybe you should start with a smaller array

Comment: how to fix the big array problem?

Comment: @BEIXIN - Changing code in a question **after** you have received answers are not the way to do it on SO. Now the answers looks stupid even though they were initially correct. If you want to add a code update, you should leave the original code as it was and then add the updated code below and explain that it is an update. Please revert.

Comment: @BEIXIN Either reduce the number of elements or allocate it on the heap using `malloc` or by making it a global variable (by declaring it outside any function).

Answer (score 2):

This for-loop

```
for( int a=0;a<number;a++){
```

seems wrong. It makes you recalculate `total` for each new input number. Try to remove the for-loop. Like:

```
while ((scanf("%f",&values[number])) != EOF )
{
    total=total+values[number];
    if(values[number]>max) max=values[number];
    if(values[number]<min) min=values[number];
    number++; 
}
```

Also, this line seems wrong:

```
mean=total/(float)(number-1);
```

I think you need

```
mean=total/number;
```

but don't do this calculation if `number` is zero, i.e. do:

```
mean = (number != 0) ? mean=total/number : 0;
```

Finally, this line:

```
float values[999999];
```

It is a huge array as a local variable. Maybe you'll have stack overflow. Try a smaller array size or use dynamic memory allocation. Notice: For a program like this, you don't even need the array. Just a single float and then do the calculations for each new input.

Finally, you should check that `scanf` returns 1. If it doesn't `values[number]` is uninitialized and should not be used. Try:

```
while ((scanf("%f",&values[number])) == 1 )
```

Comment: i dont know why my for-loop is included by the while-loop  without using "{ }",  and seems EOF count a number, so i do (number-1)

Comment: @BEIXIN - Because you don't have a `;` at the end of the `while`

Comment: how to use    float *values     here

Comment: @BEIXIN - not sure what your asking in your last comment

Comment: [Getting a stack overflow exception when declaring a large array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array)

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop needs to either have an empty set of braces, like this:

```
while ((scanf("%f",&values[number++])) != EOF )
{
}
```

or it needs a null statement, like this:

```
while ((scanf("%f",&values[number++])) != EOF )
    ;
```

Otherwise, the compiler thinks that the `for` loop is the body of the `while` loop. Note that the compiler doesn't care about white space, so it ignores the fact that the `for` loop is not indented.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main( void )
{
    float values;
    int number=0;
    float max=-100000,min=100000,total=0,mean=0;

    while ((scanf("%f",&values)) != EOF ){
        number++;
        total=total+values;
        if(values>max){max=values;}
        if(values<min){min=values;}
        }
    mean=total/(float)number;
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n",min,max,mean);

}
```

Comment: There are 2-3 bugs in this code. Did you even read my answer?

Comment: `while ((scanf("%f",&values)) != EOF ){ ... }` is an infinite loop should the user enter non-numeric data.

Comment: Why `min=100000`?  Why not `min=100001` or even better `min=FLT_MAX`.

Comment: where? but i run it ok