# Use 2D-arrray. Segmentation fault - C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm doing some exercise online, so I have some problems. 
I don't know where is problem in my code. It's return `Segmentation fault` when I run code! 
My code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, q, buff;
    int k[100000], i[100000], j[100000], a[100000][300000];
    int c;



   cin >> n >> q;


    for(buff=0; buff<n; buff++) {
        cin >> k[buff];
        //array
        for(c = 0;c < k[buff]; c++) {
           cin >> a[buff][c];  // <-- I think problem is here!
       }
    }


    for(buff = 0; buff < q; buff++) {
        cin >> i[buff];
    }


    for(buff = 0; buff < q; buff++) {
        cin >> j[buff];
    }   


    return 0;
}
```

Please help me! Sorry for my english.

Comment: These arrays are way too big to be allocated locally (on stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of such large arrays in the stack causes stack overflow. See [Getting a stack overflow exception when declaring a large array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array).

Use `std::vector` instead.

```
std::vector<int> k{100000};
std::vector<int> i{100000};
std::vector<int> j{100000};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a{100000, std::vector<int>{300000}};
```

Comment: Hey. That's the name of the website.

Comment: This is my snippet: https://pastebin.com/E0biLAKL, however, It's not work!

Comment: You are using `int n,p,i,j,c,a[100000][100000];` `a` is still large array,

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an array of **30000000000 integers**.
Considering 64-bit system, size of **int = 4 bytes**, therefore total required size is around **120 GB**, which is not available on the system stack.

This is the reason for stack overflow error.

**Solution**, use vectors instead of arrays in this situation.