# Write sorted in ascending order numbers that were drawn more than once. [ C ]

Tags: c

I can't solve this one 
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWHHU.png)

this code has Time limit exceeded, so i need to make time complexity smoller, i think

```
  #include <stdio.h> 
  int main() 
  {
    int a[100000], i, j, min, b, tmp;
    scanf("%d", &b); 
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
      min = a[i];
      tmp = i;
      for (j = i; j < b-1; j++) 
      {
        if (min > a[j]) 
        {
           min = a[j];
           tmp = j;
        }
      }
      a[tmp] = a[i];
      a[i] = min;
      if (i > 0) 
      {
        if (a[i-2] != a[i] && a[i] == a[i-1]) printf("%d\n", a[i]);
      }   
    }

    return 0;
  };
```

Comment: Sorting logic is inefficient. Shouldn't `j=i` be `j=i+1`? And correspondingly `i<b-1`?

Comment: but answer is correct

Comment: Okay if you wish to stick with this only though you are making unnecessary comparisons. Your current logic has **O(n^2)** complexity. A lot of sorts give better time complexity than this.

Comment: Do i need to sort first array at all? Maybe just answers array

Comment: The specification names the number of lotteries `n` but you re-name this `b` in your program. Why, are you trying to confuse the reader on purpose? Overall, give your variables _meaningful_ names, not a, b, c. Also, allocating 100,000 integers on the stack is a really bad idea, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array. As for the sorting algorithm, do you have to re-invent the wheel? Is there a reason why you can't call `qsort`, or at the very least implement sorting yourself with quicksort or merge sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting algorithm has complexity `O(n^2)`. For an input with size `10^5` it takes many magnitude more than `O(nlogn)` quick sort algorithm.

Here you can use `qsort()` to solve the problem.

```
qsort(a, b, sizeof int, cmp);
```

Where `cmp` is

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(int *) a - *(int *) b);
}
```

The algorithm after sorting is much more simpler.

```
int p = a[0], ct=0;
for(size_t i = 1; i<=b-1; i++)
{
    if( a[i] == a[i-1])
       ct++;
    else{
       if( ct > 1){
       // a[i-1] should be printed.
       }
       ct = 1;
    }
}
if( ct > 1){
   //a[b-1] should also be print.
}
```

The idea is something like this

> - As the numbers are sorted we will get a monotonic sequence.
> - We compare every number with one that came before. If there is duplicate they will appear next to next.
> - We only collect those numbers which appear multiple times.

Also there are few things you can follow

- Declaring large variables inside a method sometimes is constrained by the available memory(automatic storage duration).(may have stackoverflow etc) Make it global.(something of static storage duration).
- The variable names are not a bit `readable`.
- You can get help in case of using a sorting algorithm.
- Knowing the complexity of different algorithms helps. The thing is in your case the complexity is O(n^2). The sorting algorithm better than this is the popular merge sort etc. This simple idea solves the problem in your case.

You can check yourself that this code is atleast a bit more readable than your version. This helps avoid small mistakes.

> ```
>  int temp = a[0], count=0;
> for(size_t i = 1; i<=len-1; i++)
> {
>     if( arr[i] == arr[i-1])
>        count++;
>     else{
>        if( count > 1){
>        // a[i-1] should be printed.
>        }
>        count = 1;
>     }
> }
> if( count > 1){
>    //arr[len-1] should also be print.
> }
> ```