# print even odd characters separately in a string

Tags: c, string

Here is my code what I have tried,

I have to take a string from the user and as output i have to print the characters at even places  and at odd places separated by a space

MY PROBLEM:
In every test case i am assigning to both the strings at end a null character to conclude that my string has ended. Lets suppose i enter 2 test cases and  now if enter  a smaller string than first test case in result it is printing my character of 2nd test case but also printing the characters of test case because first string was larger than second

I want to ask how it can be possible if i have ended the string with a null character in every test case?

so why it is printing the value after the null character because that were the characters of previous test case because that string was larger and its character are still there in array but it should print till null character  Please help me to achieve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
   int t,i,j,k;
   scanf("%d ",&t);
   while(t>0){
       char s[10000],s1[10000],s2[100000];
      scanf("%s",s);
       for( i=0,j=0,k=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
           if(i%2==0)
               s1[j++]=s[i];
           else
                s2[k++]=s[i];


       }
       s1[strlen(s1)]='\0';
       s2[strlen(s2)]='\0';
       printf("%s %s\n",s1,s2);
       t--;

   }
}
```

Comment: Read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). StackOverflow is not a do-my-work service. Read also carefully the reference of every standard function you are using (e.g. of [strlen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), of [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), etc...)

Comment: This does not make sense: `s1[strlen(s1)]='\0';` If there was something different than `'\0'` at that position, `strlen` would have returned another value. You need to use index `j` and `k` to put the terminating 0 byte

Comment: You must read this FAQ: [Getting a stack overflow exception when declaring a large array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   s1[strlen(s1)]='\0';
   s2[strlen(s2)]='\0';
```

This line is erroneous. Replace it with

```
   s1[j]='\0';
   s2[k]='\0';
```

This is because `strlen()` only works with checking `null` in a `null` terminated string. And at this point your generated string is not yet `null` terminated.

Comment: last test case is not passing

Comment: it is saying that process terminated due to timeout

Comment: can anyone tell me the solution

Comment: What are your test strings ?plz share

Comment: https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/18927/input09.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1535556477&Signature=Tp3ZBOxcfxs27DzY99sc55c%2FLkw%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: this is my final test case in which i am failing it contains nearly 1 billion characters in a string

Comment: Ok, I will look in to this and will update you. For now make sure that char s[10000],s1[10000],s2[100000]; are big enough to hold the strings. As I see first 2 are 10000 and last one is 100000.

Comment: You want to store one billion characters in a char array?

Comment: sorry in constraint length of string is max 10000

Comment: Declaring arbitrarily huge arrays to avoid buffer overflows is bad practice. If you really don't know in advance how large a buffer needs to be, use malloc or realloc to dynamically allocate and extend the buffer as necessary, possibly using a smaller, fixed-sized buffer as an intermediary.

Comment: but how can i use malloc if user is directly entering the string

Comment: if user will enter the number of character first then i can use malloc

Comment: or if i can use malloc in this case? then how

Comment: Please correct size of the arrays as suggested in last comment.

Comment: I got it thanx you rizwan sir