# How many bytes can a read function reads?

Tags: c, unistd.h

I am doing a function that reads a line from a file. Inside this function I use the function read (man 2 read) and the number of bytes from the read function is set by the user. This function is a exercise from my school. The prototype is something like this

```
get_next_line(int fd, char **line);
```

And the read function I´m using this way:

```
read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)
```

To compile this program the user should use the flag -D BUFFER_SIZE=xx. The BUFFER_SIZE is a macro to define the nbytes from the read function.

I have no issues about how to do this exercise. **My main problem is to understand how many bytes does a read function can handle.**

I have noticed that if I input 10000000 in my BUFFER_SIZE I get a segmentation fault, and using the sanitize flag it brings me this error:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==84594==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffee85a0f20 (pc 0x000106cd68f7 bp 0x7ffee8f2a710 sp 0x7ffee85a0e40 T0)
    #0 0x106cd68f6 in ft_readfile (a.out:x86_64+0x1000018f6)
    #1 0x106cd6fba in get_next_line (a.out:x86_64+0x100001fba)
    #2 0x106cd7a7a in main (a.out:x86_64+0x100002a7a)
    #3 0x7fff652af3d4 in start (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x163d4)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow (a.out:x86_64+0x1000018f6) in ft_readfile
==84594==ABORTING
[1]    84594 abort      ./a.out
```

The ft_readfile is where I use the read function. I have tried to find this info but i couldn´t find anywhere.

**Is there a max size of bytes that the read function can read?**
**If so, how many bytes can it handle and why does it have this limit?**

**EDIT**

Those are the information asked:

The buf is defined like this:

```
char        buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
```

The function that it reads the file is like this:

```
int         ft_readfile(int fd, t_list *lst)
{
    int         res;
    char        buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    char        *tmp;

    tmp = lst->content;
    if (lst->content == NULL)
        lst->content = ft_strdup("");
    else
        lst->content = ft_substr(lst->content, ft_strlen_char(lst->content,
                    '\n') + 1, ft_strlen_char(lst->content, '\0'));
    free(tmp);
    buf[0] = '\0';
    while (!(ft_haschr(buf, '\n')) && (res = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE)))
    {
        if (res == -1)
            return (-1);
        buf[res] = '\0';
        tmp = lst->content;
        lst->content = ft_strjoin(lst->content, buf);
        free(tmp);
    }
    return (res);
}
```

Comment: How is `buf` defined?

Comment: You need to show more code. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is: `stack-overflow`.  Your stack is less than 10,000,000 bytes.  Try defining `buf` to be global.

Comment: Did you declare buf as a local variable? It seems your local variable's size is too big.

Comment: Does it work if you compile with `-D BUFFER_SIZE=5000`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky , yes it works with this size.

Comment: @FiddlingBits , I can´t use globals in this exercise.

Comment: @JohnPark , yes it´s a local variable. O can´t define globals in this exercise.

Comment: @WincentyBertoniLech: Can you use dynamic memory allocation, such as `malloc()` ? That way, you will be allocating memory on the heap instead of the stack, and you will not be getting a stack overflow. However, you should check the return value of `malloc()`, as that function can fail if you ask for too much memory.

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array

Comment: @Jabberwocky , tkz that question was indeed the answer. When i use a calloc it fixed the problem. Didn´t realize that the issue was in the memory allocation of buf.

Comment: @WincentyBertoniLech don't forget to free the memory abtained with `calloc`. BTw: afre you sure you need a buffer that big anyway?

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I will free, tkz for the tip. The size it´s because of the exercise. It says to input very big numbers. It´s good because now I know that if the input it´s a huge number I will have to use malloc or calloc instead of buf[something].

Comment: Is puting 9 space between return type and function name an specific coding style?

Comment: Closed so can't answer, but look within stat(2) to use the definition of st_blksize. This provides the specific block size of a device, which is often BUFSIZ.  BUFSIZ is what the implementation considers proper and st_blksize the actual device. . 

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html