# How to create two structures of same type but different member array sizes (no malloc)

Tags: c

I have a byte buffer structure, used for handling incoming binary data from different sources (serial, file, tcp, etc.).
I would like to try and have one `ByteBuffer` (seen below) interface, that has an actual byte array as a member, but with the option of different actual sizes of the byte buffer. **Avoiding dynamic memory allocation.**

Easier to explain in code

```
struct ByteBuffer {
  /* Indicies of the next byte to check/process, and the last byte added to the buffer */
  int front;
  int back;
  /* The actual byte buffer */
  uint8_t buf[1024];
};

struct ByteBuffer my_awesome_buffer;
/* Do something with the buffer */
void process_buffer(&my_awesome_buffer);

/* Now this is where I would like to have different ByteBuffers with different buf[] sizes
 
  For example, the serial port interface has less data incoming so it probably only needs a 
few kb, where the tcp connection has got a lot more, and needs more on the MB level
*/
struct ByteBuffer my_serial_buffer; // somehow its got a 1kb (1024) buf[] array
struct ByteBuffer my_tcp_buffer; // somehow its got a 1Mb buf[] array

/* The processing mechanism is the same for each buffer */
void process_buffer(& my_serial_buffer);
void process_buffer(& my_tcp_buffer);
```

Any approaches on how this can be accomplished, if at all? I was trying to do something with flexible arrays (C99) but couldn't get anything to work without malloc.

Comment: You either need to decide on a fixed maximum size and have all your structs use it, or allocate the appropriate size for each.

Comment: "*flexible arrays*" Do you mean VLAs ? (*Variable Length Arrays*) Those are legal C (*in newer standards*), but not very performant , you will find it better to declare a sensibly sized fixed array that you do not fully use as long as it can fit in the stack. This was also discovered by systemd and Linux kernel devs when fixing some issues caused due to VLAs, and they were mostly removed from the code.

Comment: Research [Flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).  Might meet your need.

Comment: user2840470, How do you expect `process_buffer()` to receive info about the  size to the member `buf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store a pointer instead.

```
struct ByteBuffer {
  int front;
  int back;
  uint8_t *buf;
};
```

Then you can allocate any size buffer however you like.

```
struct ByteBuffer my_awesome_buffer;
uint8_t buf1[1024];
my_awesome_buffer.buf = buf1;

struct ByteBuffer my_tcp_buffer;
uint8_t buf2[1024*1024];
my_tcp_buffer.buf = buf2;
```

Comment: This is good. Alternatively, and probably more readably, OP can simply declare different `struct`s for different bufffers.

Comment: I would also add an element `size_t size;` to the structure to enable generic handling. (`front` and `back` should be of type `size_t`, anyway, this is a code smell introduced by the OP.)

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for the example and answer, what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

To preface this answer, I think storing a pointer in a named struct (and probably using dynamic memory allocation) is a more appropriate general solution.

That being said, here is a semi-solution to your question. This code uses a macro, `CREATE_NEW_BYTE_BUFFER` to create an anonymous struct type and give it the name `buffer_name`. Its `buf` member will have size `buffer_size`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CREATE_NEW_BYTE_BUFFER(buffer_name, buffer_size) \
    struct {                                             \
        int front;                                       \
        int back;                                        \
        uint8_t buf[buffer_size];                        \
    } buffer_name;

void some_function(uint8_t *buf, size_t buf_size /* int front, int back */) {
    memset(buf, 0, buf_size); /* Do something real with the buffer here... */
}

int main(void) {
    CREATE_NEW_BYTE_BUFFER(my_serial_buffer, 1024);
    CREATE_NEW_BYTE_BUFFER(my_tcp_buffer, 65536);

    some_function(my_serial_buffer.buf, sizeof(my_serial_buffer.buf));
    some_function(my_tcp_buffer.buf, sizeof(my_tcp_buffer.buf));

    return 0;
}
```

In general, be careful not to store [too large of an array on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571945/getting-a-stack-overflow-exception-when-declaring-a-large-array).

Also, the [standard warnings about macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives) apply.

Comment: Interesting approach, have given me some ideas. I like it. Also thanks for the links for additional readings/gotchas

Answer (score 0):

> ... option of different actual sizes of the byte buffer.
> **Avoiding dynamic memory allocation.**
> ... to work without malloc.

Code could overlay `struct ByteBuffer` with a  [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) (FAM) over a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA: selectively available since C99)

I would not recommend it though for large buffers.

```
struct ByteBuffer {
  int front;
  int back;
  uint8_t buf[];
};

void foo2(void) {
  unsigned sz = rand()%100 + 1;
  _Alignas(struct ByteBuffer) char b[sizeof (struct ByteBuffer) + sz];
  struct ByteBuffer *bb = (struct ByteBuffer *) b;
  bb->front = 0;
  bb->back = sz-1;
  memset(bb->buf, 42, sz);
  // ...
  process_buffer(bb);
}
```

---

Note: `sizeof (struct ByteBuffer)` does not include memory for the FAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you don't mind some type casting. Let's say you've got your byte buffer:

```
struct ByteBuffer {
    int front;
    int back;
    uint8_t buf[8];
};
```

There's no reason that you can't create another struct with the same fields but a larger buffer:

```
struct BigByteBuffer {
    int front;
    int back;
    uint8_t buf[16];
};
```

So now you've got two different structs with the same fields, except that `buf` fields are different sizes. Now, let's say that your `process_buffer()` function does something simple, like printing the sum of the bytes from `front` up to but not including `back` in the buffer. And let's say that you create one each of your two buffers like so:

```
struct ByteBuffer b1 = {0, 8, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
struct BigByteBuffer b2 = {0, 16, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
```

So, now you can process `b1` like:

```
process_buffer(&b1);
```

and it'll add up the bytes and print 36. But if you try the same with `b2`, you get a compiler warning:

```
byte_buffer.c:31:17: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct BigByteBuffer *' to parameter of type
  'struct ByteBuffer *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    process_buffer(&b2);
```

You can eliminate this warning by casting the pointer to the expected type:

```
process_buffer((struct ByteBuffer *)&b2);
```

You're basically telling the compiler: "I know this isn't the type that you're expecting, but trust me, it'll be okay." And it *will* be okay, because the two structures have all their fields in the same places relative to the beginning of the struct. With the cast above, the code compiles fine and `process_buffer()` again prints the sum of the bytes, 72.

Here's a complete program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct ByteBuffer {
    int front;
    int back;
    uint8_t buf[8];
};

struct BigByteBuffer {
    int front;
    int back;
    uint8_t buf[16];
};

void process_buffer(struct ByteBuffer *buffer);

void process_buffer(struct ByteBuffer *buffer) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = buffer->front; i < buffer->back; i++) {
        sum += buffer->buf[i];
    }
    printf("the sum is %ld\n", sum);
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct ByteBuffer b1 = {0, 8, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
    struct BigByteBuffer b2 = {0, 16, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
    
    process_buffer(&b1);
    process_buffer((struct ByteBuffer *)&b2);
    
    return 0;
};
```

Now, you asked for two structures *of the same type* with different sizes, and to be fair that's not really what I've shown you. Instead, you've got two *different* types that are similar enough that they can be used the same way, with the same functions.