# stack overflow multi layer perceptron

Tags: c++, neural-network, stack-overflow, perceptron

I'm trying to build a multi-layer perceptron network in c++   using visual studio 2013. First I create a struct for the neutrons of the first layer but when I run it gives me a stack overflow error. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// Number of Neurons
#define INPUTS 784
#define INPNEUR 784
#define HIDNEUR 500
#define OUTNEUR 10

struct inpneuron {
int number;
double weights[INPUTS];
double bias;
double inputs[INPUTS];
double output;
double delta;
};

typedef struct inpneuron InpNeuron;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int i, j, x[INPUTS];

InpNeuron InputLayer[INPNEUR];

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

And the exception it gives is: Unhandled exception at 0x00302CB7 in Multi Layer Perceptron MNIST.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00522000).

I have very little experience in programming but I think it's a memory problem because when I decrease the number of neurons or inputs it works. Is there any way I can make it work with this number of neurons and inputs?

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
 InpNeuron InputLayer[INPNEUR];
```

allocates a huge amount of memory on the stack, more than is available by default. You should use a `std::vector` instead:

```
 std::vector<InpNeuron> InputLayer(INPNEUR);
```

to allocate the necessary memory safely from the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Your "stack-allocated data structure" is simply too large.  Please read about [Stack Overflow causes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158/) and the [difference between the stack and the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap).

Then try:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   int i, j, x[INPUTS];

   InpNeuron * InputLayer = new InpNeuron[INPNEUR];

   system("PAUSE");

   delete[] InputLayer;
   return 0;
}
```

That gets you to the basic "a-ha" of the difference between where stack and heap allocations are done.  **But** after you've absorbed the point and read a bit, you need to read about std::vector and ways to avoid raw pointer memory management...as these are much safer ways to work in C++.

Comment: Don't confuse them with `new`!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well...maybe if someone is writing a program called `Multi Layer Perceptron MNIST.exe`, they might be able to handle the facts of the stack/heap distinction...and find more use out of direction on hard data about the limits of tackling large data structures.  Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Well your program seems to be too big to fit into the stack.
A few suggestions:

1- Move to linux, it gives you more freedom on the size of the stack.

2- Use floats instead of doubles, they require less resources and will give you enough of accuracy for training.

3- Since you're not really skilled in programming, maybe you can use some already created libraries like [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org)? You can either implement your own network on Caffe very easily, or use some of their pre-implemented networks for MNIST there; They have implementations of LeNet and many other famous networks.

4- After reading the other answers: Use the heap! Using pointers instead, but you need to watch out for your memory management!

Best of luck