# Javascript Nightmare

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am new to javascript and wanted to convert my python A* algorithm to a js version so I can use it in a website.

I have tried to copy it over however I have run into an issue seen here:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded  script.js:34 
    at Array.includes (<anonymous>)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:34)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:40)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:40)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:40)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:40)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:40)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:40)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:40)
    at Graph.add_edge (script.js:40)
```

Please see my code here https://pastebin.com/4gTm3enA

I am running the JS through a blank website with a button to call the start up function

EDIT: here is my code pasted in here instead of Pastebin -

```
class Node {
    constructor(name, g, h) {
        this.name = name;
        this.g = g;
        this.h = h;
        this.f = 0;
    }

}

class Edge {
    constructor(n1, n2, w) {
        this.node_1 = n1;
        this.node_2 = n2;
        this.weight = w;
    }
}

class Graph {
    constructor(start, end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.edges = new Array();
        this.nodes = new Array(start, end);
    }
    add_node(node) {
        if (this.nodes.includes(node)) {
            console.log('This node is already in the graph');
        } else {
            this.nodes.push(node);
        }
    }
    add_edge(n1, n2, w) {
        if (!(this.nodes.includes(n1))) {
            this.add_node(n1);
        }
        if (!(this.nodes.includes(n2))) {
            this.add_node(n2);
        }
        this.add_edge(n1, n2, w);
    }
    get_edges() {
        return this.edges;
    }
    get_nodes() {
        return this.nodes;
    }
}
function start_up(){
    console.log('running');
    var sn = new Node('a', 4, 4);
    var mn = new Node('b', 2, 2);
    var en = new Node('z', 0, 0);

    var e1 = new Edge(sn, mn, 2);
    var e2 = new Edge(mn, en, 2);

    var g = new Graph(sn, en);

    g.add_edge(sn, mn);
    g.add_edge(mn, en);

    a_star(g, new Array(), new Array(), sn);
}

function a_star(graph, visited, path, current) {
    var edges = graph.get_edges();
    var nodes = graph.get_nodes();

    if (current != graph.end) {
        visited.push(current);
        path.push(current.name);

        console.log("Current Node: " + current);
        console.log('Visited Nodes: ' + visited);

        c_from_c = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
            if (current.name in edges[i]){
                tmp = edges[i].replace(current.name, '');
                c_from_c.push(tmp);
            }
        }
        var available_nodes = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < c_from_c.length; i++){
            var f = parseInt(c_from_c[i][0]);
            for (j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++){
                if (nodes[j].name == c_from_c[i][0]){
                    f += nodes[j].h;
                    nodes[j].f = f;
                    available_nodes.push(nodes[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        var f_val = new Array();
        for (j = 0; j < available_nodes.length; j++){
            f_val.push(available_nodes[j].f)
        }
        var index = available_nodes.findIndex(Math.min(f_val));

        var current = available_nodes[index];

        a_star(graph, visited, path, current);
    }
    else {
        visited.push(current);
        var shortest = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < visited.length; i++){
            shortest.push(visited[i])
        }
        console.log(shortest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your code as text _in_ the question. Not behind a link.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to have your code *in* stackoverflow. Can you import the relevant code here? Instead of pasting the link?

Comment: @Reality it should be there now: i wasnt sure if you needed it all so i put it there

Comment: How are you supposed to get out of add_edge? You're missing a base case to return from.

Comment: What is the goal of  `this.add_edge(n1, n2, w)` _inside_ of your `add_edge()` function. You are calling the function it is in, with the exact same values. How do you expect that function to ever exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add_edge` is recursively calling itself. This leads to an infinite call stack that the program just can't put up with, thus throwing the stack overflow error (*[not to be confused with the company **Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158/how-does-a-stack-overflow-occur-and-how-do-you-prevent-it) :)* ).

I don't know what *exactly* you want with this, nor can I read your mind on what you want done here, but definitely *don't* call it recursively like that.

If you find yourself needing it call itself again and again, then there are better alternatives, like `window.setInterval` or `window.requestAnimationFrame` that *don't* blow the stack.

Otherwise, add a "return" statement before the recursive callback if a certain condition is met, or put the callback statement in a conditional that will/won't execute if a certain condition is met.