# Rust Multi-threading Memory Allocation on the RP Pico/RP2040

Tags: rust, embedded, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I'm working with the Raspberry PI Pico to perform the basic task of reading data from a UART signal, modifying it, and writing it back out to a different UART address. However, I need to simultaneously be constantly monitoring an on-board sensor and sending the values it generates as well.

I found a good example at [cortexm-threads](https://crates.io/crates/cortexm-threads) but it performs some stack allocation like this:

```
let mut stack1 = [0xDEADBEEF; 512];
let mut stack2 = [0xDEADBEEF; 512];
```

How do I know (or find out) what memory addresses I can allocate the stacks to on the RP2040/Pico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example, the `0xDEADBEEF` will denote the initial per-cell value of `stack1` and `stack2` arrays, and can be set to anything. Since those arrays are function-local non-constants/non-statics, they will end up in the (main thread) stack.

Just make sure that the arrays are large enough for your use case, otherwise risking a stack overflow ([How does a "stack overflow" occur and how do you prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158/how-does-a-stack-overflow-occur-and-how-do-you-prevent-it)).

Regarding on where those variables end up being located in the device memory space: `cortex-m` will set the initial SP value to the largest possible memory address (`0x20040000` on Pico - RP2040 SRAM is located between `0x20000000` and `0x20040000`, sized 256 kB). See https://github.com/rust-embedded/cortex-m/blob/657af97d66b7157d6a6e5704d86dd59b398e7108/cortex-m-rt/link.x.in#L63. Thereby, the location of those variables will be close to the end of SRAM. See also https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/memory-layout.html

Regarding the multicore use case, see also https://github.com/rp-rs/rp-hal/blob/427344667e9f24f03d132fa08e2dfaa709bc805d/rp2040-hal/src/multicore.rs.

You could also achieve the similar functionality (but using only one core) with interrupt-driven approach, where you store each incoming UART-byte into a circular buffer, handle on-board sensor read on a (either DMA/timer) interrupt, and process the circular buffer (and possibly read sensor value) contents in the idle loop. For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer and https://rtic.rs/,